# why execute insert got NoHostAvailable in cassandra 3.1?

Tags: cassandra

When i execute insert statement in Cassandra , it got NoHostAvailable which I have a available node .

I run a singleton apache-cassandra-3.11.3 at windows 7 .

[image]

Comment: Not enough information to know for sure, can be as simple as the 127.0.0.1 node is down. Was localhost node down? whats the replication factor of `packt`? maybe include nodetool status?

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon consistency and RF. I can see there is some warning also while you are connecting to cqlsh.

Comment: Issue in my case was RF. I had 3 nodes and RF=3 but internode communication was blocked it seems on GCP.

Comment: Okay, then you need to check the connection and ports between the nodes.